# SharePoint Designer Workflow - Wait for Field Change help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, custom-actions

i'm fairly new to SharePoint and i'm having some trouble trying to create a fully functional workflow for a certain job in SP Designer and was hoping somebody may be able to come up with a solution?

Basically the process needs to go like this:

A staff member uploads a document into a document library.

The document is then required to be marked as "Approved", "Rejected" or "Referred" after being reviewed by a committee of Admin staff.

(There is a data column with those 3 status options set up as a drop down list when editing the properties of the document that will allow an admin to change the status.)

Depending on the whether the document has been Approved, Rejected or Referred, it will be copied into one of 3 different folders (Approved) (Rejected) (Referred) and then deleted from the initial folder.

On SPD, I have created a workflow which looks like this: 
[image]
Currently this works just fine using the Wait for Field Change action, but ONLY if the status is Approved.

I cannot seem to figure out how to add an OR statement or run this action in parallel with another but for the Rejected or Referred Statuses? Adding another stage does not work since the workflow does not move forward unless the document is Approved as per the first stage.

How can i modify this workflow so that IF the selected status is Rejected or Referred the document can be copied to its associated folder as with Approved one?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that 'Wait' might time out.  I've read quite a lot about workflows that time out if they are running for too long.

Explore using a 'reusable' workflow for Approvals, they appear (are perhaps are) complex to begin with, but are well worth persevering with.  This is a kind of OOTB workflow.  They are also customisable to a degree (e.g. the automatic emails that are sent out can be reworded and you can embed field:values in to them.

[image: Reusable Workflow]

Actually, [you could try this method too](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-approve-documents-without-building-a-workflow/), I really like this blog and rate it highly.  There's no need for you to invent this kind of approval workflow from scratch, so don't feel bad for abandoning what you have made so far!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to run the workflow on the "item changed" condition. And use the if-else condition to check the status of current item. Like this:

```
If(Current Item Status equals Approved)
    Copy document in current item to Approved
Else
    If(Current Item Status equals Rejected) 
         Copy document in current item to Rejected
    Else
         If(Current Item Status equals Reffered) 
             Copy document in current item to Reffered
```

This will solve your problem definitely.

Comment: have you tried this?